Is there a program or built-in function that automatically separates variables for separable ODE?
Is there a program or built-in function that automatically separates variables for separable ODE?
Note: The separable ODE referred to in this question is after variable substitution. Therefore, I hope that mma can automatically check the given ODE and complete the variable substitution, and separate the separable ODE variables.
Example 1, making a substitution to transform the differential equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{~d} x}=\frac{x-y+1}{x+y-3}
$$.
into
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} X}{X}=\frac{1+u}{1-2 u-u^2} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Where,
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}X=x-1 \\ Y=y-2\end{array}\right.
$$
$$
u=\frac{Y}{X}
$$
Example 2, making a substitution to transform the differential equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{~d} x}=(x+y)^2
$$
into
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{~d} x}=1+u^2
$$
Where
$$
u=x+y
$$
I would like to ask if there is a general program or built-in function that can automatically perform this task, rather than a specific program for these two ODEs.
Thanks in advance!

These DEs are not separable. They can be transformed to separable ones. It should be possible to separate separable ones. I think finding transformations is difficult. DSolve probably does it sometimes, although it might choose a different solution method in other cases.

For instance, DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`SeparateVariables[(1 + x - y)/(-3 + x + y), x, y] returns failed, but DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`SeparateVariables[(1 + x - y)/(-3 + x + y) /. {x -> (x + y)/Sqrt[2], y -> (x - y)/Sqrt[2]}, x, y] succeeds.

see how-to-determine-if-rhs-of-first-order-ode-is-separable-or-linear-or-neither-pa  and Leonid Shifrin answer how-can-i-separate-a-separable-function  But I found some cases where these do not detect. So I have added 60 more patterns in my own ode solver as extra checks. But the above should do it for most common separable ode's. btw, your odes are not separable.

automatically separates variables for separable ODE? may be there is different convention you are using for separable ode. For me, a separable ode  is $y'=F(x,y)$ which can be written as $y'=f(x) g(y)$ and the goal then is to find if $F(x,y)=f(x) g(y)$  and ofcourse to find $f(x),g(y)$. The above linked to answer does that. But as I said, there are few edge cases it might not work for. But for most common odes', it works fine.

Thank you for your very valuable comments, and I ' ll take the time to study what you mentioned. For separable ODE, what I describe is not accurate enough and has been updated.

For your second case example, this is known (described here) but it will not work if the RHS (what is inside the parentheses, not the whole thing ) is nonlinear in $x$ or $y$. i.e. try this $y'=(x^2+y)^2$ then you will find the transformation will not work and will not make it separable. Same for $y'=(x+y^2)^2$.

@Nasser Thank you very much for your comments, your links have been very helpful to me.

@Goofy Commentedyesterday Thank you for your comments, but I couldn't get either of the two pieces of code you provided to run successfully. I'm not sure why. My version is v14.0.

The second example
The following transforms any ode of the form   $y'= (a x + b y + c)^{\frac{n}{m}}$ into separable ode  $u'=a+b u^{\frac{n}{m}}$

Currently, this aborts if unable to do the transformation. Future version can be made more user friendly :)
Code
match[rhs_, y_Symbol, x_Symbol, u_Symbol] := Module[{a, b, c, n, e},
  If[Not[MatchQ[rhs, e_.*(a_.*x + b_.*y + c_.)^n_]], Abort[]];
  {e, a, b, c, n} = 
   rhs /. e_.*(a_.*x + b_.*y + c_.)^n_ :> {e, a, b, c, n};
  D[u[x], x] == e*(b*u[x]^n + a)
  ]
makeSeparable[ode_Equal, y_[x_], u_[x_]] := Module[{rhs},
  rhs = SolveValues[ode, D[y[x], x]];
  If[Length[rhs] == 0, Abort[]];
  rhs = Simplify[rhs];
  rhs = rhs /. y[x] -> y;
  Map[match[#, y, x, u] &, rhs]
  ]

Test
testCases = {y'[x] == (a*x + b*y[x] + c)^(n/m), y'[x] == (x + y[x])^2,
   x == y[x] - y'[x]^3, y'[x]^2 == x - y[x], y'[x]^3 + x - y[x] == 0, 
  y'[x] == (x + y[x] + 3)^2, y'[x] == (x + y[x] + 99)^(3/2), 
  y'[x] == (5*x + 9*y[x])^5}

Grid[{#, makeSeparable[#, y[x], u[x]]} & /@ testCases, Frame -> All]

The first example
This is called homogeneous ode of class C and can be transformed to separable also using general algorithm if it is possible to find the mapping X,Y.
The following transforms $y'= \frac{a_0 x + b_0 y + c_0}{a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1} $ to separable. Little error checking is done.

Code
findTransformation[ode_Equal, y_Symbol, x_Symbol, fx_, fy_, u_Symbol, 
  X_Symbol, Y_Symbol] := Module[{x0, y0, e, newODE, rhs, eq, sol},

  newODE = DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve]
     [ode, y[x], x], Y[X], X, {x == X + x0, y[x] == Y[X] + y0}];

  newODE = newODE[[1]];
  rhs = SolveValues[newODE, D[Y[X], X]];
  If[Length[rhs] > 1, Abort[], rhs = Normal@First@rhs]; 
  rhs = Normal[rhs /. Y[X] -> Y];
  eq = 1 == -(X*D[rhs, X])/(Y*D[rhs, Y]);
  sol = SolveAlways[eq, {X, Y}]; (*solve for x0,y0*)
  newODE = newODE /. sol;

  newODE = DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve]
     [newODE, Y[X], X], u[X], X, Y[X] == u[X]*X];

  Solve[newODE[[1]], u'[X]]
  ]

homogCToSep[ode_Equal, y_, x_, u_, X_, Y_] := 
 Module[{e, rhs, z, fx, fy},
  e = Map[Not@FreeQ[ode, #] &, {Abs, Piecewise}];
  If[AnyTrue[e, # == True &], Abort[]];
  rhs = SolveValues[ode, D[y[x], x]];
  If[Length[rhs] > 1, Abort[], rhs = Normal@First@rhs]; 
  rhs = Normal[rhs /. y[x] -> y];
  fx = Normal[D[rhs, x]];
  If[fx == 0, Abort[]];
  fy = Normal[D[rhs, y]];
  If[fy == 0, Abort[]];
  findTransformation[ode, y, x, fx, fy, u, X, Y]
  ]

Test
testCases = {y'[x] == (x - y[x] + 1)/(x + y[x] - 3), 
  x^2*y'[x] == (1 + 2*x - y[x])^2, (x - a)^2*y'[x] + 
    k*(x + y[x] - a)^2 + y[x]^2 == 0, (1 + y[x])*y'[x] == 
   x + y[x], (1 + x + y[x])*y'[x] + 1 + 4*x + 3*y[x] == 0, 
  y'[x] == (1 + x - 3*y[x])/(3 - x - y[x]), 
  y'[x] == (11 - 4*x + 3*y[x])/(3 - x + y[x]), 
  y'[x] == (-5 - x + 2*y[x])/(4 + 2*x - y[x]), (1 - 3*x + y[x])*
    y'[x] == 2*x - 2*y[x], (a + b + x + y[x])^2*y'[x] == 
   2*(a + y[x])^2, (1 - 3*x - y[x])^2*
    y'[x] == (1 - 2*y[x])*(3 - 6*x - 4*y[x])}


Grid[{#, homogCToSep[#, y, x, u, X, Y]} & /@ testCases, Frame -> All]


how can I output the expressions for u, X, and Y

This version returns the $X,Y$ mapping found, To obtain $u$, the newODE needs to be solved. Here is modified version of the above for the First example which now returns the $u$ ode in form that can be solve by DSolve and also returns X,Y
Version 8/17/2024
To answer comment

how can I output the expressions for u, X, and Y

findTransformation[ode_Equal,y_Symbol,x_Symbol,fx_,fy_,u_Symbol,X_Symbol,Y_Symbol]:=Module[{x0,y0,e,newODE,rhs,eq,sol},newODE=DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][ode,y[x],x],Y[X],X,{x==X+x0,y[x]==Y[X]+y0}];
newODE=newODE[[1]];
rhs=SolveValues[newODE,D[Y[X],X]];
If[Length[rhs]>1,Abort[],rhs=Normal@First@rhs];
rhs=Normal[rhs/. Y[X]->Y];
eq=1==-(X*D[rhs,X])/(Y*D[rhs,Y]);
sol=SolveAlways[eq,{X,Y}];(*solve for x0,y0*)
newODE=newODE/. sol;

newODE=DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][newODE,Y[X],X],u[X],X,Y[X]==u[X]*X];
{First@newODE[[1]],{x==X+x0,y[x]==Y[X]+y0}/.sol}
]

To use do
ode = y'[x] == (x - y[x] + 1)/(x + y[x] - 3);
{newODE, transformation} = homogCToSep[ode, y, x, u, X, Y]


To find $u$ then do
 DSolve[newODE, u[X], X]


To find $y(x)$ which is the solution to original ode, we just need to reverse the transformation done, which is just algebraic operation now. This is not shown since question asked just to convert the ode to separable but this is easy to do if you want to add it to your own code.
See Y[X] == u[X]*X for the relation. Then knowing $X,Y$ we now find $y(x)$ given $u$.

Great job! It solves the two main forms of ODEs with substitutable and separable variables and is highly generalizable. Thank you!

By the way, how can I output the expressions for u, X, and Y for each ODE substitution?

@lotus2019 added version of findTransformation which now also returns the $X,Y$ mapping used to obtain the $U[X]$ ode. To find $U[X]$, need to solve this separable ode ofcourse.

I have a question: I want u in Example 1 to be a function of both x and y, but the code  gives u as a function of only x. I would like the variable substitution to be:  $$
u=\frac{Y}{X}=\frac{y-2}{x-1}
$$Is it possible to achieve this? Thank you!

@lotus2019 Yes, but this part is not automated. But since we know that $u=\frac{Y}{X}$ and $X,Y$ are now returned back, then all what is needed is to do eq=u==Y/X; eq/.{X->x-1,Y->y-2} which gives
$$
u=\frac{y-2}{x-1}
$$ you could modify the code to return the mapping $X,Y$ as rules instead to make this easier to do. But everything you need is there now.  If you are writing a full ode solver for this, then these things ofcourse have to be done by your functions internally. But the hard part is in finding $X,Y$ if possible, and the rest is just manipulation of symbols.

The ODE D[y[x], x] == (x - y[x] + 5)/(x - y[x] - 2) could not be successfully separated using homogCToSep.  output:  (*  {u[X] + X Derivative[1][u][X], {x == X + x0$109257,
y[x] == y0$109257 + Y[X]}}  *)

@lotus2019 you are right. My implementation is not fully complete actually. I knew that. There are few cases where it does not convert homog type C to separable. To be able to cover all cases, I need to add more code. I just never had the time to do that.  Maple dsolve does detect this as homog type C and converts to separable.  One day I hope to complete my implementation of this.  Btw, this ode can be solved as exact type ode instead.
